# Want to add buttons that increase and decrease velocity of my balls?

Tags: javascript, variables, button

Would like to increase and decrease my velocity with a button (starting of with increasing).

'dl' is my velocity variable.

At the beginning:

```
'var dl = 20;'
```

JS:

```
var faster;
function speedInc(choice) {
    faster = choice;
    updateUI();
}

function updateUI() {
if (faster == "yes" ) {
    function speedInc() {
        var dl = dl +1;
    }
}
```

HMTL:

```
<input type="button" id="Faster" onclick="speedInc('yes')"> Faster? </button>
```

Comment: @Archer ah right...was blinded by the nested one

Comment: @charlietfl I only know because I almost posted the same comment.  I need to go home - done enough for 1 day :)

Answer (score 2):

`var dl = dl +1;` inside function `speedInc` is creating a local variable, & it is not updating the `dl` which is declared outside the function. Also `speedInc` inside `updateUI` is never called & there is no need of the function `speedInc`. Beside there is also no use of the variable `faster`. Rather just pass the parameter from click handler to the function

```
var dl = 20;
    function speedInc(choice) {
        updateUI(choice);
    }

    function updateUI(selectedVal) {
    if (selectedVal=== "yes" ) {
        dl = dl +1;
     }
    }
```

Comment: Awesome!, so the HTML should work, and then just that? because I thought that the function was the process in which the variables value changed?

Answer (score 1):

You are redeclaring the speed variable as a local variable in `updateUI`. try removing the `var` from that line.

```
function updateUI() {
    if (faster == "yes" ) {
        dl = dl +1;
    }
}
```

When you write var inside a function, it is making a new variable within the scope of that function. What you want is to change the global speed variable.